# Select multiple columns but distinct only one in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

Lets say I have a table called TABLE with the columns col1, col2, col3 and col4

I want to select col1, col2 and col3 but distinct col2 values from the others, but I can't do it.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "col1", "col2", "col3" FROM [Table] WHERE col1 = Values
```

But the output brings me more than one record of col 2 with the same value.
I know that is because the distinct filtered all the columns that i specified, but i don't know how to get all the columns and filter only the values of col2.

Is it possible to SELECT more than 1 column but filter only one of them with SELECT DISTINCT ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you have to tell which row you want for a col2 value.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it

Answer (score 0):

As you said, distinct just limits the full set of columns to eliminate duplicates. Instead, I'd just use an aggregate function with a GROUP BY statement.

```
SELECT MAX(col1) AS col1, col2, 
MAX(col3) AS col3
FROM tbl
GROUP BY col2
```

That will take the top value alphanumerically from the supplied columns. Or, to list all values separated by commas:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(col1,',') AS col1, col2, 
STRING_AGG(col3,',') AS col3
FROM tbl
GROUP BY col2
```